# Finding column and row name for maximum value in each row

Tags: python

I have a dataset like this

[image]

I want to get highest marks for students across subjects along with the student name and the subject name in which they got the highest marks. In this case, I should get something like

```
1 A Math 96 
2 B Physics 89
3 C Math 88
4 D Physics 81
5 E English 87
```

I have used  df_merged.max(axis=1)`to get max values for each row but unable to figure the column row and student name part with it. Tried idmax function but it gives the AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'idmax'

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What about physics 94, english 91?

Comment: Please add the code you've written so far along with a reproducible example.

Comment: Please show the *correct* expected output from your example as well as the code you tried to solve your problem ([MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: df_merged.max(axis=1)
Out[128]: 
0      96
1      89
2      88
3      81
4      87
5      94

I would like to get student name and the subject in which they had highest marks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `idxmax(1)` which gets you the index of the max grade, and `max(1)` which gets you the highest grade, and `concat` them together row-wise based on your `index` which we can set to be the 'Student' column:

```
df.set_index('Student',inplace=True)
pd.concat([df.idxmax(1),df.max(1)],axis=1)
```

prints:

```
Student             
A           Math  96
B        Physics  89
C           Math  88
D        Physics  81
E        English  87
F        Physics  94
```

including `1` in `idxmax()` and `max()` is an alias for `axis=1` which performs the operation row-wise.

Comment: Thank you for response. But I am facing this difficulty with datatypes. I get this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'idmax'. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: what version of ```pandas``` are you using? I use ```1.2.0```